# Multi-thread dead lock:Will this design cause dead lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Thread A: set the variable m_bPaused and the m_pPauseEvent is a semaphore object which provides wait() and set() interface.
Thread A call this to pause:

```
PausePlay(){
    m_bPaused = true;           // A1

    m_pPauseEvent->Wait(0);     //A2 wait for the B thread is enter to the waiting
}
```

Thread B:

```
    if (m_bPaused)
   {
       m_pPauseEvent->Set();    //B1
       m_pPauseEvent->Wait(0);  //B2 0 wait forever 
   }
```

And call Thread A to continue Thread B:

```
    m_bPaused = false;    //A3

    m_pPauseEvent->Set(); //A4
```

When I pause, I wait until the B1 is executed.Thread A returns.Will here be dead lock?  when I call the continue in Thread A,and run to A3. In the mean time thread B is still beteen B1 and and B2, then thead A finish the row m_pPauseEvent->Set(). Thread B will never received the signal sent by A4.Dead lock! Will this happen?

Comment: are your events manual-reset or auto-reset. It will make a difference, especially with this code. Btw, what you need (honestly) is a condition variable + mutex pair. particularly in thread B. you need to be able to set the condition (the predicate notification by another name) **and** begin waiting as an atomic operation.

Comment: I can sure that is manual reset .

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not post the implementation of your event classes there might be multiple issues in your code.

1. As already mentioned your access to m_bPaused might be an issue.
2. Thread B calls `Set()` right before `Wait(0)`. Are you sure that thread A will get notified or does Thread B consume the notification.
3. In nearly all multi thread classes there is the problem of a spurious wake. It seems that your Thread B is not protected against this.

So it is really hard to tell if this code will be deadlock free or not.

Comment: +1. I actually think based on that Set()-Wait() assumption that A will consume it before B does just in itself is suggestive this can DL. And if it can, you have to assume it will, and therefore need to fix it.

Comment: `EventTypeWrapper EventWindows::Wait(unsigned long maxTime)
{
    unsigned long res = WaitForSingleObject(_event, maxTime);
 
}`

Comment: The set is just call the SetEvent windows api

Comment: @MIKU_LINK_SUCCESS: Ok, so this will also not work. You cannot guarantee that Thread A gets kicked out of the wait state. It is possible that B sets the event and right after consumes it's own set with the Wait.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for sure. `m_bPaused` is possibly a non-atomic variable which means the concurrent access is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: If I pack m_bPaused to multiple thread safe ,will all the problem be solved?

Comment: "pack" ? Also, there's the larger scale problem. Is the code from Thread B executed in a loop? I.e. is `(m_bPaused)` tested repeatedly?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Events do not guarantee that a signal wakes one of the current waiters. This is the cause of the known issue with `PulseEvent` and missed wakeups, because the event is set and then cleared, but the set might not be seen by the waiting threads.

In this case, the `Wait` call following the `Set` call may wake rather than the `Wait` call on the other thread. This means that there is no synchronization protecting accesses to `m_bPaused`, which is UB, and also means that the wrong thread has woken.